# Connection Error while connecting sqlite database to linqpad

Tags: database, sqlite, linqpad

I have a sqlite database file having .sql extension. I can access the database using sqlite console application. Now I want to access this database through linqpad. I am using IQ driver (MySQL, SQLite, Oracle) version 2.0.7.0 for connecting with sqlite database. However, I am getting this error message:
**Connection Error: File opened that is not a database filefile is encrypted or is not a database**
I do not know, What is wrong and I am just location database file with driver. Can anyone help me and identify my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schema and Data were both present in same file and due to which I was getting this error. So I read the xyz.sql file in sqlite console and then created the backup. Then I loaded that backup file in linqpad using IQ driver and then every thing behaving well as it should.